# Saving all the permutations

Tags: c

I would like to write a function that generates all the permutations of a number and store them into a 2D array. I know how to print out all the permutations of a given number using the recursive method but I can't figure out how to save each one into an array.

```
void permute(int *arr, int left, int right, int **per, int rows)
{
int k = 0, j;

if(left == right)
{
    for(j = 0; j <= right; j++)
        printf("%d ", arr[j]);
    printf("\n");
    /*(for(j = 0; j <= right; j++)
    {
        per[k][j] = arr[j];
        k++;
        if(k == rows)
        eturn;
    }*/
}
for(j = left; j <= right; j++)
{
    swap(arr + left, arr + j);
    permute(arr, left + 1, right, per, rows);
    swap(arr + left, arr + j);
}
}

int main(void)
{
int a[3], i, j, **b;

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    a[i] = i;
b = malloc(4 * sizeof(int *));
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    b[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
permute(a, 0, 2, b, 4);
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    printf("\n");
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        printf("%d ", b[i][j]);
}
printf("\n");
return 0;
```

}

So for example this code will print out the permutations of 0123. I want b(2D array) to hold the first 4 generated permutations. What I mean is that permutations of 0123 are:

```
0 1 2 |
0 2 1 |
1 0 2 |
1 2 0 |
2 1 0 |
2 0 1
```

and b(2D array) has:

```
2 0 1 |
0 0 0 |
0 0 0 |
0 0 0 |
```

Comment: Please at least show what you have tried doing and point out where exactly you are struggling. As is it sounds as if you should consult a basic C tutorial instead

Comment: Ok I edited my question.

Comment: 1) make 2D-array. 2) recursive call 3) Add to the array if completion of one permutation

Comment: What do you mean by "all the permutations of a given number"?. For example, what are all the permutations of 1020?

Comment: @George.L you need to put an input example and desired output your expect from it. You need to add that in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: 1 0 2 0 | 
1 0 0 2 |
1 2 0 0 |
1 2 0 0 |
1 0 2 0 |
1 0 0 2 |
0 1 2 0 |
0 1 0 2 |
0 2 1 0 |
0 2 0 1 |
0 0 2 1 |
0 0 1 2 |
2 0 1 0 |
2 0 0 1 |
2 1 0 0 |
2 1 0 0 |
2 0 1 0 |
2 0 0 1 |
0 0 2 1 |
0 0 1 2 |
0 2 0 1 |
0 2 1 0 |
0 1 2 0 |
0 1 0 2|

Comment: Also, if function `permute` indeed takes that number as input, which one of the arguments is it? There are several arguments, none of them seems like an input number (at least not by name).

Comment: you need `result[3!][3]`

Comment: I would think of a permutation as something without those spaces that you mention (otherwise, there are only 3 different values). Now, assuming I'm correct, do you want each permutation as an integer or as text? Because you will not be able to "describe" leading zeros unless you use text. Also, I would expect to see you extracting those decimal digits in your code. So there should be `% 10` somewhere in your code, which I haven't found as of yet.

Comment: I want each permutation as an integer. The number that is going to be permuted is given as an array

Comment: `b = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));` is wrong; `*b` is a pointer to `int`, and pointers do not necessarily have the same size as `int`. It is best to write it as: `b = malloc(4 * sizeof *b);`, this will use the right size.

Comment: Yeah I deleted that by mistake before posting the question. What I had written was b = malloc(4 * sizeof(int *));

Answer (score 1):

First, have a look at your `permute()` function:

```
void permute(int *arr, int left, int right, int **per, int rows)
```

The first three parameters are necessary to keep track of the permutations themselves. The last two parameters are the array to store the permutations in, and the number of rows in that array. What is missing is another `int` that tells the function how many rows have already been filled in, so lets add that:

```
void permute(int *arr, int left, int right, int **per, int rows, int rows_filled)
```

In `main()`, you just call `permute(a, 0, 2, b, 4, 0)`. In `permute()` itself, you now know where in the array you have to write the result:

```
if(rows_filled < rows) {
  for(j = 0; j <= right; j++)
    per[rows_filled][j] = arr[j];
  rows_filled++;
}
```

Comment: Dont I just do that with k? Also where exactly do I put that piece of code? Inside the condition that left == right?

Comment: @George.L: no, you don't do that with `k`, because that is a local variable. Every time you call `permute()`, that function call gets its own variable `k`, which is initialized to `0` every time.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to keep track of the current number of rows filled. And you also need a way to increment the number so that it is visible to all invocations of `permute`.

Therefore I'll suggest that you extend the function with a `int*` that points to the "next row to be filled". By using a pointer, you can increment the integer it points to from `permute`and it will immediately be visible in all invocations of the function.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int*a, int* b)
{
  int temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}

void permute(int *arr, int left, int right, int **per, int* pRow, int rows)
{
  int j;

  if(left == right)
  {
    for(j = 0; j <= right; j++)
    {
      printf("%d ", arr[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    if (*pRow < rows)               // Check for free rows
    {
      for(j = 0; j <= right; j++)
      {
        per[*pRow][j] = arr[j];     // Fill the row
      }
      ++(*pRow);                    // Increment row-to-be-filled
    }
  }

  for(j = left; j <= right; j++)
  {
    swap(arr + left, arr + j);
    permute(arr, left + 1, right, per, pRow, rows);
    swap(arr + left, arr + j);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  int a[3], i, j, **b;

  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  a[i] = i;
  b = malloc(4 * sizeof(int *));
  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  b[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
  int row = 0;                     // variable to hold row number for next row to fill
  permute(a, 0, 2, b, &row, 4);    // pass a pointer to the variable
  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    printf("\n");
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    printf("%d ", b[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2
0 2 1
1 0 2
1 2 0
2 1 0
2 0 1

0 1 2
0 2 1
1 0 2
1 2 0
```

Comment: Oh man thank you very much. How I hadn't thought about it? Thanks again!